# How do I know the current user liked corresponding link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I make a page tab application. The application displays some items, each of which has a like button. Like buttons attached to the corresponding url item. I need to display to users who liked, some text in those elements that have collected 10+ likes.
So, I write this code:

```
// Get a link statistics
$link_stat = $fb->api(
    array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => 'SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://myurl.com/item1.html"'
    )
);

if ((int)$link_stat[0]['like_count'] > 10)
{
    //Get like by current user_id and link object_id
    $like = $fb->api(
        array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => 'SELECT user_id, object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me() AND object_id IN (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url="http://myurl.com/item1.html")'
        )
    );

    var_dump($like);
}
```

I run this code upon request permission *user_likes* and *read_stream*, but it outputs `array(0) { }`.
A question is, how do I know the current user liked corresponding link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, sh… I didn't notice that there is a table **[url_like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/)** (or recently emerged?).
I made this FQL query, and it returned the required response:

```
SELECT user_id FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me() AND url = "http://myurl.com/item1.html"
```

Cpilko, thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 0):

You could try rewriting your query to go at it the other way. See if your url exists in a user's likes.

This works for me:

```
SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE id IN (SELECT object_id FROM like 
       WHERE user_id=me()) AND strpos(url, "myurl.com/item1") >= 0
```

Comment: So, there is a problem: I liked some items, but they don't appear in my list of likes. All links is external and public.

Comment: That is always a problem. FQL has limits to what it returns and Facebook doesn't always tell you what those limits are. You could try adding `LIMIT 99999` to your inner query, but YMMV. You could also try requesting this via the Graph API methods instead of FQL. Again YMMV.

Comment: The limitations of these queries seem to be a "feature" within Facebook. They seem to be intentionally hobbling the amount of data returned to third-party apps by the `like` table specifically to stop people from walling content behind a like button.